# TinyMCE 4.3 only uploading one image

Tags: javascript, tinymce

TinyMCE is not allowing multiple file uploads in a post. You can select a file, and it will insert into the TinyMCE editor however once you submit, only the last inserted image is uploaded.

Below is the code I am working with: (the [0] is removed on the second attempt in which I was thinking TinyMCE would handle the files array)

```
if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
    $('#upload').trigger('click')
    $('#upload').on('change', function() {
        var file = this.files[0]
        var reader = new FileReader()

        var name = file.name.split('.')[0]
        var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(name, file, reader.result)
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);
     reader.onload = function(e) {
        callback(blobInfo.blobUri(), {
                    alt: file.name,
                    title: name
                })
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    })
}
}
```

I have tried to append additional files with a for loop and removed the [0] from files and split without success.

```
file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
  if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
    $('#upload').trigger('click')
      $('#upload').on('change', function() {

      var file = this.files//[0]
      var reader = new FileReader()

      var name = []
      for(var x = 0; x < file.length; x++) {
        name.push(file[x].name.split('.'))
      }

      var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache
      var blobInfo = blobCache.create(name, file, reader.result)
      blobCache.add(blobInfo);       
      reader.onload = function(e) {
       callback(blobInfo.blobUri(), {alt: file.name, title: name})
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    })
  }
}
```

I have also tried allowing auto upload which only work for the first image and the rest fallback to base64 in the database. Lastly, I tried to combine all files in order to upload however I'm not seeing different file names in console.log. For instance I attach one file, I see one file in console.log, I attach another, I see two responses in console.log but with the most recent attached file but only the last attached image will upload on submit. It seems that TinyMCE overwrites the file with each image attachemnt.

Is there a different approach to this so I can add images to a post with TinyMCE and upon submit, they are all uploaded instead of the last image attached?

Comment: Logs show an image uploaded as a blob then the file upload script called with the appropriate { "location": "/someimage.jpg"} response, but any additional attempt to add more images results in just image blobs but no call to the upload script. Oddly each attempt of an attached image with TinyMCE results in an increase by 1, so two blobs for the first attachment, then three then four etc.

Comment: Modifying the following now allows for image uploads but on submit it will upload the very last image that was attached and disregard the following code that was:  var name = file.name.split('.')[0] and changed to:  var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();

Answer (score 0):

Changed to the following now for a working solution. Using the name for the first argument when calling blobCache.create was the cause of the issue, a unique blobid is required instead.

```
    file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
      if (meta.filetype == 'image') {

          $('#upload').on('change', function() {
              var file = this.files[0]
             var reader = new FileReader()

          reader.onload = function(e) {
              // var name = file.name.split('.')[0] // replaced with id below
              // var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1]; // for base64
              var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
              var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache
              var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, reader.result)
              blobCache.add(blobInfo);
               callback(blobInfo.blobUri(), {alt: file.name, title: name})
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        })
        $('#upload').trigger('click')
      }
    }
```